# Why does the comparison operator not work after enumeration?

Tags: powershell, comparison

I have pretty simple use case below where I need to find if certain element of Array exists. Why conditional operator in this case is not working?

```
@("a", "b").Where{$_ -eq "a"} -eq $true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`.Where()` array method acts as a *filter*** (just like its cmdlet counterpart, `Where-Object`), so it **returns a *subarray<sup>[1]</sup> of matching elements*, not a Boolean**.

For **simple equality testing**<sup>[2]</sup>, you can use the Boolean [**`-contains`** operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains) instead:

```
('a', 'b') -contains 'a' # -> $true
```

If you do need a more sophisticated, **scriptblock-based test** via [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where):

```
('a', 'b').Where({ $_ -in 'a', 'z' }, 'First').Count -ne 0
```

Note the the `'First'` argument, which, as an important optimization, makes `.Where()` return after the first match is found.

Since the result is always wrapped in an array<sup>[1]</sup>, checking the `.Count` property is sufficient to determine if a match was found.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, a collection of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` is returned.</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that PowerShell is case-*insensitive* by default, but it offers `c`-prefixed versions of its comparison operators for case-sensitive operations; e.g., `-ccontains`, or for the equivalent operands-reversed [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in), `-cin`.</sup>

Comment: There is also `"a" -in @("a", "b")`, `@("a", "b").Contains("a")` and `@("a", "b").IndexOf("a") -ge 0` and other ways, but I personally like the 2 from this answer best.

Comment: Good addition, @marsze, thanks; note that `.Contains()` and `.IndexOf()` are case-_sensitive_.